# Are $14$ and $21$ the only "interesting" numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

The numbers $14$ and $21$ are quite interesting.

The prime factorisation of $14$ is $2\cdot 7$ and the prime factorisation of $14+1$ is $3\cdot 5$. Note that $3$ is the prime after $2$ and $5$ is the prime before $7$.

Similarly, the prime factorisation of $21$ is $7\cdot 3$ and the prime factorisation of $21+1$ is $11\cdot 2$. Again, $11$ is the prime after $7$ and $2$ is the prime before $3$.

In other words, they both satisfy the following definition:

> **Definition:** A positive integer $n$ is called ***interesting*** if it has a prime factorisation $n=pq$ with $p\ne q$ such that the prime factorisation of $n+1$ is $p'q'$ where $p'$ is the prime after $p$ and $q'$ the prime before $q$.

Are there other interesting numbers?

Comment: If $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime, then we search examples for $p_{n+1}p_{m-1}-p_np_m=1$. I have seen this before... but where?

Comment: Since one of $n$ and $n+1$ is even, you either have $p=2$ and $p'=3$ or $q'=2$ and $q=3$, so that either $q={3q'-1\over2}$ (if $pp'=2\cdot3$) or $p'={3p+1\over2}$ (if $q'q=2\cdot3$).  The Prime Number Theorem limits the number of possibilities, and it should be fairly easy to find the upper limit. In effect, you want to find when a "$3/2$" version of Bertrand's Postulate kicks in.

Comment: Given that there is no known general relation between the prime factorization of $N$ and the prime factorization of $N+1$ (except for the fact that they are always disjoint multi-sets, i.e., share no common elements), the answer to your question is most likely also unknown.

Comment: @BarryCipra If you see [this wikipedia paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results), they say that the $\frac65$ version of Bertrand's postulate kicks in at $25$. The $\frac32$ version can't kick in later, so there aren't a whole lot of primes that needs to be checked.

Comment: @barakmanos See the comment right above yours.

Comment: @Arthur, excellent, thanks.  Do you want to write up an answer, or shall I?

Comment: @BarryCipra You do it. It's your result. Also, I got enough upvotes already from an answer basically referring to Bertrand's postulate (it's my most upvoted answer yet).

Comment: Well, Parcly Taxel has relieved us both of the burden.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question I thought it was gonna be the parody about Ramanujan's $14=7\cdot 2=2\cdot 7$.

Comment: I think we should drop the requirement $p\ne q$ and accept $n=9$ as an interesting number as well.

Comment: I wonder if I am the only one who read the title and thought of Taxi numbers.

Comment: They become a lot less interesting when you realize that they are the only ones

Comment: This is not ideal terminology. 'Interesting numbers' are a standard meta-mathematical concept, and the proof that there are no uninteresting numbers is the example par excellence of a meta-mathematical theorem.

Comment: Finding primes such as $p_{n+1}p_{m-1}-p_np_m = 2$ might be more interesting. Like $5 \cdot 7 - 3 \cdot 11$

Comment: Coincidentally I asked a fairly similar question on Quora last week: [Is there any special name for the sequence of smallest consecutive pairs of numbers (m,m+1) whose factorizations contain all the first n primes?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-special-name-for-the-sequence-of-smallest-consecutive-pairs-of-numbers-m-m+1-whose-factorizations-contain-all-the-first-n-primes)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Note that exactly one of $n$ and $n+1$ is even. It follows that for $n$ to be interesting, either $n=3p$ and $n+1=2N(p)$ or $n=2p$ and $n+1=3P(p)$, where $P(p)$ and $N(p)$ are the previous and next primes to $p$ respectively. Rearranging we get that $p$ must satisfy one of the following two equations:
$$\frac{3p+1}2=N(p)\tag1$$
$$\frac{2p+1}3=P(p)\tag2$$
However, by [a 1952 result of Jitsuro Nagura](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195570997), for $p\ge25$ there is always a prime between $p$ and $\frac65p$. In particular, if $p\ge31$ is a prime:
$$\frac56p<P(p)<p<N(p)<\frac65p$$
But when $p\ge31$ the following inequalities are also true:
$$\frac{2p+1}3<\frac56p\qquad\frac65p<\frac{3p+1}2$$
Therefore, if $p$ is to satisfy $(1)$ or $(2)$ above, it must be less than 31. This leaves a handful of cases to check for $p$, and we find that *the only interesting numbers are 14 and 21* as conjectured.

---

The Nagura paper is a reference in the Wikipedia article on [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). While those in the comments had saw it, sketching out the approach I use here, I already knew what to do; I did not read those comments in detail until after posting my answer.

Comment: For the record, it is worth pointing out that this method was previously sketched in the comments to the question by Barry Cipra and Arthur, including a link to Wikipedia (which cites Nagura's paper).

Comment: Even as a non-mathematician, that paper was great to read, interesting approach (though probably interesting mainly because I'm not well versed in the field).