# What is the smallest $r$ such that there is always a prime between $n$ and $rn$ for large enough $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

From Bertrand's postulate we know that when $n\ge2$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$. From the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996120/are-14-and-21-the-only-interesting-numbers), we know that for $n\ge31$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $\frac65n$. Let $r>1$. I fully expect the following conjecture to be unproven:

> There is always an $n_0$ such that when $n \ge n_0$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $rn$.

What is the smallest known $r$ for which this is known to be true?

Comment: Why did you expect the conjecture to be unproven?

Comment: @ErickWong Because the $\dfrac 65n$ claim was only proven in the 1950's, so I guess I wasn't so optimistic about the general case having been proven in the past 60 years

Comment: Ah I see. So the general case was known in 1896, but the best upper bounds we have for $n_0$ as a function of $r$ are probably much weaker than the truth.  There are a few plausible reasons why the first publication of $6/5$ might be so late: 1) the result isn't of intrinsic interest unless proven by elementary methods similar to Ramanujan's proof of Bertrand's postulate, 2) the explicit value of $n_0$ was arduous to verify before early computers allowed computation of Riemann zeros.

Comment: @Ovi : ​ In fact, see [this question I asked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212816/5810). ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known to be true for all $r > 1$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results), in particular this means there is no such smallest $r$.

Comment: In particular, there is no "smallest $r$", since the set of $r$ for which the claim holds does not contain its infimum.

Comment: @ErickWong: good point, thanks, I've added it.