# Generalization on a feature of 21

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$n=\prod_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{a_i}$$
where $p_i$ are prime factors and
$f$ , $g$ and $h$ are the functions
$$f(n,m)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}j^m$$
And
$$g(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_i.p_i$$
If we put $m=1,n=21$ then
$$g(f(21,1))=g(231)=21.$$

21 is only number satisfy $g(f(n,1))=n$.

[proof for 21](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131137/647719)

Now let

$$h(m) = \sum_{g(f(n,m))=n}1$$

So $h(1)=1$.

> > **Question**
> >
> > *If $m$ have finite $n$ satisfied $g(f(n,m))=n$* then what is formula for $h(m)$?
> >
> > *Can we prove there are infinitely many $m$ satisfying above statement*?

Comment: What makes you suspect there is any kind of closed form for $h(m)$?

Comment: @servaes Actually I also don't think there is any close form for $h(m)$ but maybe more interesting is, if $h(m)$ have finite value then how many such $m$ exist in which pattern

Comment: If $n$ and $n+1$ are square free $g({n(n+1)\over 2})$ is simply a sum of primes if $m$ is 1.